# How i show React tables/API?

Tags: reactjs, image, api, new-operator

Hi Guys i was trying to do and API From this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpfP60KjmZU&t=2s , but it doesnt work for me i did exactly the same thing as this guy but in a new version i changed some things of course because the Switch is different in this version but when i run my API the tables dont show like in 47:25 in the video is just the blank page with the menus but is not appearing any tables if anyone can help me im new to react and im trying to make this register table work if anyone can help me i appreciate[this is what my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaKNS.png) [this is how i need to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj4uI.png),if anyone wants the print of the code im gonna put the tabs and ask me which one you want a and i send [ask me the tab i click and i send the print i answer quickly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvOwF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Data isnt showing in my API,besides the code being right i think,when i do "Npm start" all the site loads but only the titles appear like the first print and the tables doesnt appear